# How to install a specific version of angular-animate with bower?

Tags: angularjs, bower

Im using angular 1.4.14, and I want to install angular-animate,
my json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "abc-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "angular-modal-service": "^0.10.1",
    "angular-ui-notification": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.9",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "mdPickers": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "abcFrontApp",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.14.1"
  }
}
```

with bower install, bower ignores the version and install angular-animate#1.6.0 which is incompatible with angular#1.4.14.

I think I have 2 options:

1. Upgrade angular 1.4 to 1.6 which I think could have more consequences
2. Downgrade angular-animate to 1.4

I think the most secure option is 2, so I tried to downgrade the version unsuccessfully.
 I have tried to **bower install  angular-animate#1.4.x**
but I had no matches found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `bower update angular-animate` after you have saved your `bower.json` file.

That will attempt to install the version you specified, but if bower finds a compatibility issue it will install the most compatible version, or prompt you for a resolution. You can, however, add the `-f` flag to force bower to install the version you specified.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Node Package Management(npm), you can use the following command:

`npm install angular-animate@1.4.8`

using `@x.x.x` after the package name means installing the specific version.

Comment: They specifically asked about Bower.